# Changing a script from a MySql PDO & INSERT to a PostGRESql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, post, pdo

I followed the steps at this [website](http://jdulal.com.np/post-gps-location-to-a-remote-server-with-in-an-interval/) to create a background service using Android Studio that sends GPS data to a PHP script, that then posts to a MySQL database.

However, I am wanting to post to a Postgres database.  I tried several things, but I have not had any success.  These are the two PHP scripts from the website tutorial:

config.php script:

```
<?php
class DB{
private $dbHost="localhost";
private $dbUsername="USER";
private $dbPassword="PASS";
private $dbName="locationdb";

public $db_con;

public function __construct(){
if(!isset($this->db)){
try{
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->dbHost.";dbname=".$this->dbName, $this->dbUsername, $this->dbPassword);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->db_con=$pdo;
}catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e){
die("Failed to connect with mysql :".$e->getMessage());

}
}
}

public function addGPSData($lat, $lon)
{
$sql="INSERT into tblgpslocation(latval, lonval) VALUES (:lat, :lon)";
$stmt=$this->db_con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":lat", $lat);
$stmt->bindParam(":lon", $lon);
$stmt->execute();
$newId=$this->db_con->lastInsertId();
return $newId;
}
}
?>
```

Script 2:

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$db= new DB();

if(isset($_POST['gpsdata']) && $_POST['gpsdata']=='true'){
$result=$db->addGPSData($_POST['latitude'], $_POST['longitude']);
if($result>0){
echo "OK";
}else{
echo "error";
}
}
?>
```

What changes do I need to make in order to make this connect to my postgresql database and post the incoming data?

Comment: Change the connection string and the `lastInsertId()` will require the sequence name for postgresql

Comment: $pdo=new PDO("pgsql:host=".$this->dbHost.";dbname=".$this->dbName.";user=".$this->dbUsername.";password=".$this->dbPassword);

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed fix for the code or an example?  Above is what I've come up with for the corrected connection string for PostGRESQL.

Comment: In pgsql for auto increment you would create a named sequence, use that name for the lastInsertId argument.   And do post any error code/behavior youre having.